# Skipping a CTest if the target was not built

Tags: cmake

In CMake, one can use `add_subdirectory(foo EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)` to exclude the targets defined under `foo` from being built by default **unless** they are needed by some other target, like this:

```
add_subdirectory(foo EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
add_custom_target(wanted_foo_targets ALL DEPENDS
  bar_tool  # only build bar_tool from foo
)
```

Suppose `foo` defines two targets, `bar_tool` and `foo_tool`, and tests for each:

```
add_test(NAME test_foo_tool COMMAND foo_tool) 
add_test(NAME test_bar_tool COMMAND bar_tool)
```

When you build the overall project, `foo_tool` is not built, because it is not a dependency of anything, but `bar_tool` is built because it is a dependency of `wanted_foo_targets`.

But CTest still registers the `test_foo_tool` tool, which now fails because `foo_tool` doesn't exist.

Can I remove/hide/skip tests that refer to targets that weren't built? I know I could make the test command something like `[ -f foo_tool ] && foo_tool` but this will erroneously state that the test passed.

Bonus points if I can do this from the parent directory, without modifying how the tests are set up inside `foo`. In my case, `foo` is a project provided by a third party, and I don't want to have to maintain a patch of their code as they write new tests.

Comment: I do it by passing `-E NOT_BUILT` to ctest.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by using the [SKIP_RETURN_CODE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/SKIP_RETURN_CODE.html) test property in combination with a small test driver script (which you have already considered using).

In the source code directory add a test driver script named `test_driver.sh` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -x "$1" ] ; then exec "$1" ; else exit 127 ; fi
```

The script checks for existence of a test executable passed as the first argument and exits with error code 127 (aka "command not found") if it does not exist.

In your CMakeLists.txt add the tests in the following way:

```
add_test(NAME test_foo_tool COMMAND "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test_driver.sh" $<TARGET_FILE:foo_tool>)
set_tests_properties(test_foo_tool PROPERTIES SKIP_RETURN_CODE 127)
```

When you run the tests with the executable `foo_tool` missing, ctest will report the `test_foo_tool` as a skipped test but not as a failed test.

```
$ ctest 
...
    Start 1: test_foo_tool
1/2 Test #1: test_foo_tool ....................***Skipped   0.01 sec
    Start 2: test_bar_tool
2/2 Test #2: test_bar_tool ....................   Passed    0.01 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =   0.03 sec

The following tests did not run:
      1 - test_foo_tool (Skipped)
```

Comment: I wrote a quick script to patch my project to use this: https://gist.github.com/rgov/ee76c4d0e604afcfb147c4f92bb9b1c2

Comment: I tried this, and the test does get the status "not run", but this translates to a failure.

Comment: @rgov I have updated my answer with a different approach.

Comment: Great work!  I'm actually kind of shocked that this isn't the default behavior built into ctest.

Comment: This answer recommends use of a linux `sh` script.  What about instead using Findpython to launch a python script for cross-platform support?  Or even better, have CMake compile a C program that does it, in case python isn't available?

Answer (score 1):

Tests can be disabled by setting the `DISABLED` property of the test in question.
You can also get a list of tests defined in a sub-directory by checking the `TESTS` property.

So you should be able to use `get_property` to get a lists of all the tests for that specific directory and then disable all of them. If only a sub-set of the tests needs to be disabled then filter the list of all tests, using `list(FILTER)` to just those that need to be disabled.  This is only convenient if there is a naming convention that is followed.

Unfortunately `set_property` can only modify the property of a test within the same directory not a sub-directory.  This means that the CMakeLists.txt file would need be updated.

Alternatively if modifying the CMakeLists.txt is too much of an issue just don't run those tests. That could be done by using the `ctest -E regex` option to exclude those tests.

Comment: I suppose that there's no way for me to get the test command after the fact, is there? I don't want to disable every test, just the ones that test the parts I don't link against.

Comment: After the `add_subdirectory` command try using `get_property(foo_tests DIRECTORY foo PROPERTY TESTS)`.  This should give you all the tests that were added using `add_test` in that directory.  At least that's what the documentation says.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but suppose the subdirectory defines targets TgtA and TgtB, and I only build TgtB. I want to get TgtB's tests, but skip TgtA's tests. I think your solution, so far, would disable tests for both TgtA and TgtB.

Comment: @rgov It's not a perfect solution for all cases.  But if, as described in the question, use EXCLUDE_ALL for foo then neither TgtA or TgtB in foo are built.  So excluding tests for both targets should be acceptable.  If this isn't what you mean in your question then please update the question with the exact details you need so you can get an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok, I tried to explain more. It's not necessarily the case that TgtA and TgtB are both skipped just because I used `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`, because another target can depend on one, which will force it to be built.